# How to sign a message in Python without getting an error?

Tags: python, private-key

The error is :

> TypeError:This is not a private key

I have tried this :

```
def sign_transaction(self):
    private_key = RSA.importKey(binascii.unhexlify(self.sender_private_key))
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
    h = SHA.new(str(self.to_dict()).encode('utf8'))
    return binascii.hexlify(signer.sign(h)).decode('ascii')
def verify_transaction_signature(self, sender_address, signature, transaction):
    public_key = RSA.importKey(binascii.unhexlify(sender_address))
    verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(public_key)
    h = SHA.new(str(transaction).encode('utf8'))
    return verifier.verify(h, binascii.unhexlify(signature))
```

I'm using Python 3.8 .

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to include everything needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in my database I was sending private key to public key column.
So I was trying to sign my transaction with public key instead of my private key.